Use robot framework listeners to read results file path
I have developed a couple of test libraries for robotframework very specific to my needs.
I package these libraries in a wheel and distribute it to users through PyPi and pip.
User could install this wheel using pip and run any robot or pabot command to run robot tests created using the keywords from my test libraries.
I need to upload these results file to another application. I want to use a generic solution which could work with robot and pabot both.
I did try using listeners here but have faced below challenges so far :

Listeners come with event handlers to be triggered during an execution. This allows me to get results file paths using listener functions namely output_file, log_file, report_file.

from robot.api import logger

class CustomListener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3  # Specify listener API version

    def __init__(self):
        self.output_file_path = None
        self.log_file_path = None
        self.report_file_path = None

    def output_file(self, path):
        """Called when the output file path is known."""
        self.output_file_path = path
        logger.info(f"Output file saved at: {path}")

    def log_file(self, path):
        """Called when the log file path is known."""
        self.log_file_path = path
        logger.info(f"Log file saved at: {path}")

    def report_file(self, path):
        """Called when the report file path is known."""
        self.report_file_path = path
        logger.info(f"Report file saved at: {path}")

    def close(self):
        """Called when the test execution ends."""
       #Some custom logic


This allows me to capture log file paths for robot executions but in case of pabot this listener gets registered to individual robot processes that pabot runs and not to parent pabot process.
Hence not able to read the paths in case of pabot using listeners.

In case of pabot i need to read the merged results file and upload it to another application.
As of now i havent been able to figure out an event that pabot triggers at completion or log file generation

I tried registering my upload listener in  test libraries itself but doing so as well doesnt triggers output_file, log_file and report_file functions at all.



I guess the reason why you dont get the final stuff from pabot is that pabot most likely uses rebot to combine individual log files into final versions so relying on just a listener might not work for you.
